# CodeIgniter: how do I check DB table for duplicates before entry?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm writing a small application that will write the contents of a csv file to a database in CodeIgniter, but I'm having difficulty checking for dupes before write. Since this is a fairly common task, I was wondering how some of the professionals (you) do it. For context and comparison, here is my (currently non-working) code:

```
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM salesperson WHERE salesperson_name='" . $csvarray['salesperson_name'][$i] . "'";
        $already_exists = $this->db->query($sql); 

        if (sizeof($already_exists) > 0) {

            //add to database

        }
```

Any input at all short of "You suck!" (I already hear that from my own brain twice an hour at this point) will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing will work, but as above the comparison should be "== 0" not "> 0".

You can also use CodeIgniters built in num_rows method instead of using sizeof, like so:

```
$sql = "your query";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);

if ($query->num_rows() == 0) {
  // no duplicates found, add new record
}
```

As a side note, if you're using CodeIgniter then it's worthwhile to use Active Record to build your queries instead of writing SQL. You can learn more about it here: [CodeIgniter - Active Record](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you probably want (rather than >0)

```
if (sizeof($already_exists) == 0) {
    //add to database
}
```

Also could just push all your data to a temporary staging table, which you could then clean out with some spiffy sql- and then push back to your staging table.

Taking a punt on you using mysql (either that or postgres if you are phping) You could try this (taken from http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-removing-eliminating-duplicates-from-a-mysql-table/) 
You will have to change your .ID to your primary key

```
delete from salesperson_temptable 
    USING salesperson_temptable, salesperson_temptable as vtable
    WHERE (NOT salesperson_temptable.ID=vtable.ID)
        AND (salesperson_temptable.salesperson_name=vtable.salesperson_name)
```

then when you review the contents of salesperson_temptable you can then insert it back to the salesperson table