# Codeigniter MYSQL QUERY insert_string Avoid DUPLICATE

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I would like to configure an SQL query where it would not insert again if the record exists.

Thanks in advance.

```
$name="John";
$value="login";

        $this->db->query(
            $this->db->insert_string("user_log", array(
                "user_log_user_id"  =>  $this->session->userdata("user_id"),
                "user_log_name"     =>  $name,
                "user_log_value"    =>  $value,
                "user_log_date"     =>  time()

        ))
```

If it has the same time and the same activity , it should not be inserted into the log information table.
Eg.

CURRENT ISSUE:

```
No User          Activity        Time
-- ----------    ----------      ----------
1 John           Login           01/10/2014 10:55
2 John           Login           01/10/2014 10:55
3 John           Login           01/10/2014 10:55
4 John           Logout          01/10/2014 11:00
5 John           Logout          01/10/2014 11:00
```

EXPECTED RESULT:

```
No User          Activity        Time
-- ----------    ----------      ----------
1 John           Login           01/10/2014 10:55
2 John           Logout          01/10/2014 11:00
```

Comment: Modify your SQL so that it uses `num_rows` or `count()`, or set your column as UNIQUE to avoid duplicates.

Comment: Did u mean I need to do a `SELECT` query first and then insert & set 'activity' column , 'time' column and 'User_id' column to be `UNIQUE` ?  a `UNIQUE` expression is a mixture of these three columns.. @Fred-ii-

Comment: Meaning that, in your DB interface; modify your column and set the constraint as UNIQUE. I don't know enough about CI in order to do it directly as a controller, but it can be done in the SQL itself.

Comment: Have a look at this answer on Stack http://stackoverflow.com/a/4929558/

Comment: use INSERT IGNORE QUERY to achieve this

Comment: Yes, I understand what you said. 'SELECT' and then 'INSERT'. I was thinking if I could do it with an INSERT SQL..@Fred-ii-

Comment: @xyonme See Arif's answer below.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you Fred for your attention. :)

Comment: @xyonme You're welcome, glad to know you found a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE". The following link will help you a lot I think

https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/203637/